# Кастомный тип тега script

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы работала такая конструкция:

```
<script type="text/myscript">
 myscript text
</script>
```

Т.е. задается новый тип - myscript и нужен обработчик того, что внутри скрипта такого типа

Comment: А где вы планируете это обрабатывать?

Если на сервере (php, кстати допускает конструкции `<script language="php"> phpinfo(); </script>`) - то вам надо писать или модуль или cgi-приложение, которое будет перед выдачей страниц обрабатывать эти инструкции.

Если в браузере - то нужен или плагин или какое-нть расширение для браузера.

Comment: @Борис, конструкция `<script language="php"> ... </script>` удалена в PHP7, так что ее лучше не использовать. А если говорить о браузере, то можно обойтись и без расширений -- все реализуется с использованием JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень многое зависит от того, как вы собираетесь это использовать.

Если речь идет о клиентской стороне, то вы вполне можете использовать следующий подход:

```
<script type="text/x-my-script" id="my-script">
    myscript text
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Эта функция выполняет ваш код. Когда ее вызывать - зависит от
    // логики вашего приложения.
    var run = function() {
        var source = document.getElementById('my-script').html;
        // ... здесь вы должны распарсить и выполнить ваш код
    };
</script>
```

Похожий подход применяется для хранения клиентских шаблонов (например, Handlebars.js).

Если речь идет о серверной стороне, то тут все существенно сложнее. Вам нужно сначала распарсить сам документ, вытащить код и выполнить его. Лучше не тратить на это время и использовать уже существующие языки программирования/фреймворки.

**UPD:**

При указании mime-типа скрипта (у вас `text/myscript`) рекомендуется использовать префикс `x-` (`text/x-myscript`). Это позволят сразу отличить стандартные mime-типы от специфических для данного приложения. К примеру, Handlebars.js рекомендует использовать тип `text/x-handlebars-template`.